# Find string with all sorts of html tags PHP

Tags: php

```
{
  "status" : "success",
  "prices" : [
    {
      "market_hash_name" : "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)",
      "price" : "9.77",
      "created_at" : 1463806291
    },
    {
      "market_hash_name" : "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Factory New)",
      "price" : "38.51",
      "created_at" : 1463822081
    },
    {
      "market_hash_name" : "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Field-Tested)",
      "price" : "17.8",
      "created_at" : 1463811694
    },
    {
      "market_hash_name" : "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Minimal Wear)",
      "price" : "26.0",
      "created_at" : 1463823062
    },
    {
      "market_hash_name" : "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Well-Worn)",
      "price" : "12.9",
      "created_at" : 1463832713
    },
    {
      "market_hash_name" : "AK-47 | Black Laminate (Battle-Scarred)",
      "price" : "6.36",
      "created_at" : 1463832092
    },
    {
      "market_hash_name" : "AK-47 | Black Laminate (Factory New)",
      "price" : "93.0",
      "created_at" : 1463800517
    },
    ]
}
```

Im having the following issue when im trying to loop trough the prices and preg_match for AK-47 | Black Laminate (Factory New) it doesnt seem to find it

Ive used the following code

```
$data = json_decode($json,true);
$prices = $data['prices'];
echo '<pre>';
$item = 'AK-47 | Black Laminate (Factory New)';
foreach($prices as $items ){
    foreach($items as $key=>$value){
        if(preg_match("/".$item."/i",$value )){
            echo $key."<br>";
            echo $value."<br>";
        }
    }
}
echo '</pre>';
```

Any ideas on what ive been doing wrong

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_quote` function to escape special characters inside a string used within regex pattern:

```
$data = json_decode($json,true);
$prices = $data['prices'];

$item = 'AK-47 | Black Laminate (Factory New)';
foreach ($prices as $items ){
    foreach ($items as $key => $value){
        if (preg_match("/". preg_quote($item) ."/i", $value )) {
            echo $key."<br>";
            echo $value."<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
market_hash_name
AK-47 | Black Laminate (Factory New)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in RegEx pattern, `|` and `()` are regex characheter .

you can use [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)

Try

```
 if (preg_match("/". preg_quote($item) ."/i", $value )) {
```

instead

```
if(preg_match("/".$item."/i",$value )){
```

and also you can Try  change your regex to:

```
$item = 'AK-47 \| Black Laminate \(Factory New\)';
```

Comment: Is there  way to programatically add those / to the variable $item?

Comment: @user3280648 yes use `preg_quote`